# Exception AttributeError: when I try to get Tkinter to refresh image

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I'm new to Tkinter, but I want to have my jpg image refreshed every 5 second, I've made this code, but I'm getting an exception attribute error.
 can someone guide me ??

I receive this error:

```
Exception AttributeError: "'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__ph
oto'" in <bound method PhotoImage.__del__ of <PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage object at 0
x754b16f0>> ignored


# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from Tkinter import *

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import time

window = Tk()
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
a = 0

def readimage():
        global a, img, img1, img2, imglab
        a = a +1
        img = Image.open("./web1.jpg")
        img1 = img.resize((288, 162), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img1)

readimage()

window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
window.configure(background = "black")
endbutton = Button(window, text="exit", command=window.destroy)
endbutton.grid(row=1,column=1, sticky="nw")
alabel = Label(window, text=a)
alabel.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="w")
imglab = Label(window, image=img2, bg="black",fg="white",  font=("Arial", 18))

imglab.place(relx=.6, rely=1.0,anchor="sw")
imglab.lower()

window.update()

scheduler.add_job(readimage, 'interval', seconds=5)
scheduler.start()
while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        alabel[ "text"]=a
        imglab[ "image"]=img2
        window.update()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Please include the error in your question.

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot :) have updated now.